# Selenium Web Page Element access using regex

Tags: java, selenium

```js
<input id="columns:4:fragParent:values_911" name="columns:4:fragParent:values" value="911" type="checkbox">
<label for="columns:4:fragParent:values_911">OPS - Amol Gharte</label>
<br>
<input id="columns:4:fragParent:values_973" name="columns:4:fragParent:values" value="973" type="checkbox">
<label for="columns:4:fragParent:values_973">OPS - Anand Babu</label>
<br>
<input id="columns:4:fragParent:values_1336" name="columns:4:fragParent:values" value="1336" type="checkbox">
<label for="columns:4:fragParent:values_1336">OPS - Ashwini Saravanan</label>
```

I am able to click checkbox using below code by selenium java.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='OPS - Amol Gharte']")).click();
```

But my requirement to select all "OPS". is there any possible using regex in selenium or any other possibilities

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='^OPS*']")).click();
```

i tried something like this but fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First capture all such items using:

```
  List<WebElement> itemList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'OPS')]"));
```

or using

```
List<WebElement> itemList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[starts-with(text(),'OPS')]"));
```

Then click all checkboxes one by one as below:

```
  for(WebElement item : itemList ){

      item.click();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all labels that contain "OPS", like this:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'OPS')]"))
```

Notice that I'm using "findElements". Then you can assign all those elements to an array and have a "for" loop to perform actions on each of those.

Answer (score 0):

agreed with "Sebastian L" answer, but it's better to add dash in locator (as some text could just include OPS in any other part). If you are sure that values always starts with OPS you can use:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[starts-with(text(), 'OPS -')]"))
```